# Why does the procedure I written caused the problem "IOPub data rate exceeded" in JupyterLab

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to write a procedure about splitting strings but caused the problem of "IOPub data rate exceeded" in JupyterLab.

I have searched in Google, there is a way to increase limit of IOpub data rate.But I think the code (details as below) is simple and don't understand why caused the problem。

```py
def split_string(source,split):  
    x = 0  
    y = 0 
    z = []  
    while x < len(source):  
        y = source.find(split,x) 
        z.append(source[x:y])
        print (z)
        x = y+1 
    return z
```

I would like to confirm whether there is any problem about my code. 
And how to fix it not to show the error messages below.

**“IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)”**

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have a print statement inside a while loop, if printing 'z' after every iteration is not important to you, I suggest you print it only after the calculation is done. The IO operation (the print statement) rate is very fast, and might crash jupyter, that is why you are seeing the error.